# Issue setting request content for HttpRequestMessage in Dotnet?

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I'm new to dotnet/C#, and I'm having a really hard time setting my request body when trying to make an HttpClient request. I've attempted the following:

```
string url = "https://sample-url.io";
var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
                    {
                        RequestUri = new Uri(url),
                        Method = HttpMethod.Post
                    };
request.Content = new StringContent("Test", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

However, when I print out the request, this is what I see:

```
{
   "Content":{
      "Headers":[
         {
            "Key":"Content-Type",
            "Value":[
               "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "Method":{
      "Method":"POST"
   },
   "RequestUri":"https://sample-url.io",
   "Headers":[
      
   ],
   "Properties":{
      
   }
}
```

I can't , for the life of me, figure out why `Content` does not contain the body I set (`"Test"`), and why it does contain the other parameters under that strange secondary "Header". I also tried defining Content on creation of the request variable, to no avail:

```
var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
                    {
                        RequestUri = new Uri(url),
                        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                        Content = new StringContent("Test", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
                    };
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: why are you displaying the `HttpRequestMessage` object at all? You are supposed to send that object using `httpClient.SendAsync(request);`.

Comment: @Andy Sorry, you're right, those are important details. I have to send through my request with a username and password in the body. When I send this through, I receive an error due to the fact that the body is improperly formatted. I'm just trying to see what the HttpRequestMessage looks like, since it's invalid when I send it. When I print this out, I can clearly see that it is not referencing the body I set at all in the request, and there are badly formatted "Headers" appearing in there for some reason I don't understand.

Comment: well, for starters `"Test"` isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @Andy Does it need to be JSON, in order to be assigned using StringContent? I have tried 

request.Content = new StringContent("{'TEST': 'nothing'}"); 

and this gives me the same result.

Comment: the body is not stored as a serializable property. it can't be serialized. [It's stored in content as a Stream](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System/net/System/Net/Http/HttpContent.cs). I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish here.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear how are you outputting the content. You won't see it if you just serialize it. But if you try it like this, I believe you will get the value:

```cs
Console.WriteLine(await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

On the side, yes, you specified the mediatype to `application/json` (3rd parameter on the constructor) but the content is just a plain text - there's at least some level of inconsistency.

Another way to see it is by fiddler:

[image]